# File upload in asp.net core fails if view model only contains one property

Tags: c#, file-upload, asp.net-core

I have converted an old asp.net MVC 5.2 project to asp.net core 2.0 and came across a strange problem with a file upload that did not populate its file property.

If the view model contains a single property, the file property, it will not be populated by the model binder. But if I add a dummy property to the view model and view, the file property is populated on post back.
**Update** It also works if the IFormFile property is placed directly in the view model class.

Is this a bug in asp.net core or am I missing something?

*Sample code for the view - remove the dummy input to expose the issue*

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

   @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.UploadData.Dummy) @* Removing => PostedFiles == null *@

   <input type="file" name="@Html.NameFor( m => Model.UploadData.PostedFiles )" />
   <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

*Sample code for the controller*

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public MyFileData UploadData { get; set; }
}

public class MyFileData
{
    public string Dummy { get; set; } // Removing => PostedFiles == null
    public List<IFormFile> PostedFiles { get; set; } = new List<IFormFile>();
}

public class IndexController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Index( MyViewModel vm )
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it is a problem with your nested level. It should work if you use a much lean view model. Keep the `PostedFiles` property in `MyViewModel` class

Comment: @Shyju yes that works, but why it an extra property required when the view model is nested? (My original vm is very complex)